# Check if page is mlock'd or not?

Tags: c, linux, posix

In Linux, is there any way to check if a page (or range of pages) has been `mlock`'d? The POSIX description of `munlock` suggests that it succeeds on a valid allocation no matter how many times `mlock` has been called (which would seem to include zero times).

Comment: the man page says something about /proc/PID/status it shows how many kilobytes the process has locked, maybe it shows the ranges too.

Comment: Hi, what you want to do is not easily. I just find you can check the struct_page to make sure.  
`#define FOLL_MLOCK 0x40 /* mark page as mlocked */`  you can check if your page have that flag.

Comment: @madper: That looks like a kernel flag; I'd like to test for this from userspace.

Comment: then I have no idea. sorry. :-(

Comment: There is `mincore()` but that will only tell you what pages are in memory at the moment not if they are locked.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but I think if you allocate your memory using [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and **`MAP_LOCKED`** flags, it is similar to doing a `malloc` and an `mlock`.

With this you will get an entry into [`/proc/[pid]/smaps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) **if the `CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR` kernel configuration option is enabled.**

With `/proc/[pid]/smaps` you can then check the `Locked` line of the mapping entry, which will allow you to determine if the mapping is locked (`mlock` equivalent).